# Derby Database Table Column Name Format Inconsistent in Query

Tags: database, derby

When query a Derby database,  I find out that for some tables I have to double quote the column name and use table name to qualify the column name, but for some other tables I don’t need to.  What happens to these tables and how can I make all tables the same and can query them without the double quote and the table name qualifier?  I am using NetBeans IDE’s Sql Command tool.  Below are those different queries.

```
Set schema app;
Select * from table1 where table1.”state” = ‘CA’;
Select * from table2 where state = ‘CA’;
```

Comment: In fact I found some tables also need double quote and the query is like:  Select “table3”.”customer” from “table3” where “table3”,”state” = ‘CA’;

Answer (score 3):

Putting a tablename or column name in quotes, sometimes referred to by the jargon-y term "delimited identifiers" does two things:

1. Allows you to use words that are otherwise reserved keywords (e.g., naming a column "WHERE" or "SELECT")
2. Instructs the database system to process the name using case **sensitive** rules, rather than **case-insensitive** rules

So if you originally created "table3" with a CREATE TABLE statement that specified "table3" in double quotes like this, then you will forever after have to refer to it with the name in double quotes.

`select * from table3`

will be automatically processed by the database as if it was

`select * from TABLE3`

while

`select * from "table3"`

will successfully match the table you created as `create table "table3"`

See: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/ref/crefsqlj34834.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The database is created by other people.  Your explanation on the double quote is very clear.  But why I have to qualify every column name with the table name in my query? Even I copy the old table to a new table with the following commands: create table new_table as select * from "old_table" with no data; insert into new_table select * from "old_table";

Comment: Try using the ij "show tables" and "describe" commands to examine the schema of the database. What do "show tables" and "describe" return for table "table3"?