# Queries in Derby Embedded Database

Tags: java, derby

I tried this query

```
String sql1="select * from custinf";
        try {
            stmt=conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute(sql1);
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

It throws

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'CUSTINF' does not exist.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.atuts.cms.database.Database.addCustomer(Database.java:57)
    at com.atuts.cms.database.Database.main(Database.java:31)
Caused by: ERROR 42X05: Table/View 'CUSTINF' does not exist.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePRPSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.flowExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.executeX(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

When i change the query to  `String sql1="select * from \"custinf\""`; It's working. I haven't faced this problem while using mysql db. can anybody explain it?

Comment: *Does* the table or view `CUSTINF` exist?

Comment: exist other wise second query won't work "select * from \"custinf\""

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203787/derby-database-table-column-name-format-inconsistent-in-query

Answer (score 1):

To quote from [an answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12217485/1907906):

> ```
> select * from table3
> ```
>
> will be automatically processed by the database as if it was
>
> ```
> select * from TABLE3
> ```
>
> while
>
> ```
> select * from "table3"
> ```
>
> will successfully match the table you created as `create table
>   "table3"`

So if your table was created as `custinf` you must use `"custinf"`. Using `custinf` *without quotes* will convert your query to use the table name `CUSTINF` which probably does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Derby table names are case sensitive. It may be "Custinf" or "custinf".

You may drop custinf table and recreate with proper case.