# Glassfish Database Authentication with Derby

Tags: netbeans, authentication, glassfish, derby

Would like to setup Derby database table authentication in Glassfish and Netbeans. For a start I try to use plain text passwords that are not hashed.

Struggling with this for 3 days now.

Guesses:
 1. Glassfish does not see the database.
 2. A problem with the realm in Glassfish.

Here are the Finest log entries:

```
Précis:   [Web-Security] Policy Context ID was: Coiffure/Coiffure
Précis:   [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission perm: ("javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission" "/faces/admin/j_security_check" "POST")
Précis:   [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission isGranted: true
Le plus précis:   Processing login with credentials of type: class com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.PasswordCredential
Précis:   Logging in user [admin] into realm: jdbcRealm using JAAS module: jdbcRealm
Précis:   Login module initialized: class com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.auth.login.JDBCLoginModule
Grave:   SEC1112: Cannot validate user [admin] for JDBC realm.
Précis:   Cannot validate user
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Cannot connect to the data source jdbc/Coiffure for the database user null.
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm.getConnection(JDBCRealm.java:585)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm.isUserValid(JDBCRealm.java:408)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm.authenticate(JDBCRealm.java:324)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.auth.login.JDBCLoginModule.authenticate(JDBCLoginModule.java:78)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.PasswordLoginModule.authenticateUser(PasswordLoginModule.java:116)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.BasePasswordLoginModule.login(BasePasswordLoginModule.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:383)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:241)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:154)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:695)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:636)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.processSecurityCheck(AuthenticatorBase.java:991)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/Coiffure' in SerialContext[myEnv # com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jndisuffix # __nontx, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state # com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs # com.sun.enterprise.naming [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Coiffure not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.glassfish.resourcebase.resources.naming.ResourceNamingService.lookup(ResourceNamingService.java:236)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.lookup(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupNonTxResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:553)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupNonTxResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:538)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm.getConnection(JDBCRealm.java:573)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Coiffure not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:208)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:66)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:478)
    ... 56 more
Précis:   JAAS authentication aborted.
Le plus précis:   doPasswordLogin fails
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Security Exception
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:840)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:383)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:241)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:154)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:695)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:636)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.processSecurityCheck(AuthenticatorBase.java:991)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:841)
    ... 38 more
Avertissement:   WEB9102: Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Security Exception
```

[image]

Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: What does your derby.log say? Can you verify that the Derby database is properly implementing authentication as you expect, by using a low-level JDBC tool such as Derby's IJ tool to connect to the DB? It's not obvious that you are getting to the root cause exception in your exception chain; see: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain for assistance in how to do that.

Comment: @Bryan: Thanks for the comment. Found the solution. Took me another day. I'll post the answer below for millions of other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was mostly that one needs to use UPPERCASE for table and column names when creating the tables in Derby (in Netbeans).

Wow, it is amazing that nobody else on the World Wide Web knows this.

This is the example that I followed. And I couldn't find anything wrong with it: https://sites.google.com/site/saultcollegeit/courses/csd322-java-III/authentication-and-authorization--jsf-jdbcrealms-mysql

Except that it is for a MySQL DB, so here is the code for creating the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "HENNIE"."USERS" (
  "USERID" int NOT NULL,
  "USERNAME" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  "FIRSTNAME" varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  "LASTNAME" varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  "PASSWORD" char(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("USERID")
);

CREATE TABLE "HENNIE"."GROUPS" (
  "USERNAME" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  "GROUPNAME" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("USERNAME","GROUPNAME")
);

INSERT INTO "HENNIE"."GROUPS"("USERNAME", "GROUPNAME") VALUES
  ('admin', 'admin'),
  ('jannie', 'standard');

INSERT INTO "HENNIE"."USERS"("USERID", "USERNAME", "FIRSTNAME", "LASTNAME", "PASSWORD") VALUES
  (1, 'admin', 'hennie', 'r', '8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918'), /*admin = 8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918*/
  (2, 'jannie', 'jan', 'j', 'e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855'); /*<empty string> = e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855*/
```

Notes:

1. 'hennie' was the username I used when creating the DB. The DB name is not in the code above.
2. When creating the pool and realm, the names can be quite confusing, so be careful. After creating the realm, refresh the Glassfish browser tab to see the new realm name on the left as well.
3. It helps to set one type of log entry to FINEST in GF: (a) Go to this page: http://localhost:4848/common/monitor/serverInstMonitoringServerPage.jsf .
   (b) Set this property to Finest: javax.enterprise.system.core.security

Comment: It sounds like you had this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12217485/193453 Glad you figured it out!

Comment: It seems that you are correct Bryan! And it seems Netbeans ignore case and use uppercase.